# Center text between two lines of equation

Tags: equations, align

I am currently trying to put a text between 2 lines of equations and align them with the equals sign. I have already read about this in another thread, but I cant get it to work the way I want it.

```
    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:distrib}
    \begin{aligned}
    n_c &= max\left[N \cdot z_{max} \cdot x, 2 \cdot n_{min}\right] \\
    n_{co} &= min\left[ max\left[n_c \cdot x, n_{min} \right], n_c - n_{min} \right]
    \enskip \text{where} \enskip x \sim U \left(\left[0, 1\right] \right) \\
    n_{cp} &= n_c - n_{co} \\
    n_f &= N - n_c
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
```

which gives:

[image]

Now i want to  move that "where part" between n_c and n_co, while keeping everything else the way it is, i.e. all equations aligned at the equals sign and the equation number centered, so that it looks like this: [image: text centered between lines]

Following the steps from the other thread I get:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:distrib}
\begin{aligned}
n_c &= max\left[N \cdot z_{max} \cdot x, 2 \cdot n_{min}\right] \\
n_{co} &= min\left[ max\left[n_c \cdot x, n_{min} \right], n_c - n_{min} \right] 
\end{aligned}
\enskip \text{where} \enskip x \sim U \left(\left[0, 1\right] \right)
\begin{aligned}
n_{cp} &= n_c - n_{co} \\
n_f &= N - n_c
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

However, I dont know how to move the last part into an extra line. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) not an answer to this question, but remember `\max` and `\min`

Comment: I would like to suggest that you place the "where ..." clause in an `\intertext{...}` wrapper. Next, get rid of both `aligned ` environments and use a single `split` environment inside the `equation` environment.

Comment: Thx for the suggestions to both of you. I will definitely use the \max \min functions, not sure why they got lost ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lower manually the clause:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:distrib}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
n_c    &= \max[N \cdot z_{\max} \cdot x, 2 \cdot n_{\min}]
&\quad&\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
    where $x\sim U([0,1])$%
} \\
n_{co} &= \min[\max[n_c \cdot x, n_{\min}], n_c - n_{\min}] \\
n_{cp} &= n_c - n_{co} \\
n_f    &= N - n_c
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I used `\max` and `\min` (you should, too). I also removed all `\left` and `\right` tokens, which only do evil here.

I'd also suppress all `\cdot` symbols, which are very seldom used to denote multiplication in professional math.

However, my feeling is that the clause about *x* should be moved in the text following the display.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I used `\cdot` in this equation because it looks strange to me otherwise. I dont want the reader to accidently skip parts of the formula because they think it is another variable.

Answer (score 1):

A TABstack alternative where the 1/2 line spacing is achieved by setting a 3-row stack adjacent to a 4-row TABstack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:distrib}
\ensureTABstackMath{\alignCenterstack{
n_c    =& \max[N \cdot z_{\max} \cdot x, 2 \cdot n_{\min}]\\
n_{co} =& \min[\max[n_c \cdot x, n_{\min}], n_c - n_{\min}] \\
n_{cp} =& n_c - n_{co} \\
n_f    =& N - n_c
}}
\quad
\Centerstack{where $x\sim U([0,1])$\\ \\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:distrib}
    \begin{aligned}
    n_c    &= max\left[N \cdot z_{max} \cdot x, 2 \cdot n_{min}\right] \\
    n_{co} &= min\left[ max\left[n_c \cdot x, n_{min} \right], n_c - n_{min} \right] \\
%
    & \text{where }x \sim U \left(\left[0, 1\right] \right)\\
%   
    n_{cp} &= n_c - n_{co} \\
    n_f    &= N - n_c
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]